# Adding up rows that have multiple unique values per row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I really need help with adding values together from rows with multiple lines of the same ID. The cells look as follows:
[The ID's I need to sum by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2OpT.png)
I need to sum all the expenses (found at the end of the table above in one column into a new sheet that looks as follows:
[Where I want to calculate expenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUIu5.png)
The Coding column is used to give the unique ID to a line item based on the actual line item that is found elsewhere in a budget (the KEN06 etc.) and the month. I need to sum all the expenses for each line item (that can occur more than once in a given month) for each month only.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIFS, where you can define multiple parameters (columns) and the matching values for them. Only the values (separate column) with all parameters matching what you defined will be added.

Similar to that is COUNTIFS, for simple counting of occurences by parameters. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using the `SUMIF()` formula.

I set up two short tables:

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

In Sheet 2 Column B I added this formula:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:B;Sheet2!A2;Sheet1!B:B)
```

This formula looks for all values of `Sheet2!A2` in `Sheet1!A:B` and then sums the corresponding values in `Sheet1!B`

For you to get this formula to work you would need to change the cell references and possible change the `;` to a `,` depending on your region restrictions.